# SetCursor() sometimes fails during rapid mouse movements

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cursor, sfml

I'm currently changing the Windows mouse cursor in my SFML/C++ application like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
  sf::RenderWindow window;
  window.create(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "Window", sf::Style::Close);
  static int cursorNum = 0;

  HCURSOR cursor = LoadCursorFromFile("graphics\\cursors\\cursor.cur");
  HCURSOR cursorTarget = LoadCursorFromFile("graphics\\cursors\\cursor-target.cur");

  while (window.isOpen()) {
    if (window.hasFocus()) {

      //...Irrelevant that decides the value of cursorNum...

      ////Mouse Cursors////
      if (sf::IntRect(0, 0, 1280, 720).contains(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x, sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y)) {
        switch (cursorNum) {
          case 0:
            SetCursor(cursor);
            SetClassLongPtr(window.getSystemHandle(), GCLP_HCURSOR, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(cursor));
          break;
          case 1:
            SetCursor(cursorTarget);
            SetClassLongPtr(window.getSystemHandle(), GCLP_HCURSOR, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(cursorTarget));
          break;
        }
      }
      /////////////////////
    }

    ////Clear////
    window.clear(sf::Color(30, 0, 30));
    /////////////

    window.display();
  }

  sf::Event event;
  while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
    if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
      window.close();
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This works perfectly fine except for when I move the mouse rapidly. There will be a few scarce instances where I can see the default windows mouse cursor in addition to my custom mouse cursor. Why might this be?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change cursor dynamically then you need to handle `WM_SETCURSOR` notification in your window proc. Changing cursor as a response to `WM_MOUSEMOVE` may be too late (what is probably happens in your case). I'm not sure how `WM_SETCURSOR` is supposed to be handled in SFML, maybe you will need to hide system cursor and draw one yourself.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're describing. Could you please add a code example to your answer?

Comment: Each windows receives messages through it's [WindowProc callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx). When system is about to update a cursor it sends `WM_SETCURSOR` notification that you need to handle if you want to update cursor immediately. `WindowProc` is probably somewhere in the guts of SFML so you may need to hide system cursor and draw one yourself.